# What is the efficient way to write code where argument with same value is passed to a function that is called multiple times ? (python)

Tags: python, parameters, boto3

```
def filtered_imagesIds(imageParam,serverId)
   ###code to get subset of data provided using serverId

def oldest_image(filteredImageParam)
   ### code to find oldest image  
mainfunc()
  completeImageSet = (### code to get whole set of ImageIds)
  for server in serverList:
      filteredImageSet = fitered_ImageIds(completeImageSet,server)
      oldestImage = oldest_image(filteredImageSet)
      oldImageList.append(oldestImage)
  print oldImageList
```

This is a rough skeleton of my code. As you can see I'm  trying to get oldest image for a server from filtered set of images obtained from whole set of images.

I'm new to python and I'm not sure how efficient it is to pass an argument with same value(`completeImageSet`) to a function(`filtered_ImageIds`) that will be called multiple times.

Will an object be created each time the function is called? If so would it be more efficient to have something like a global variable?

Comment: It's impossible to tell without more info.... If you're worried about arguments being passed by value (and thus paying for a copy each time you call a function) you can rest at-ease: Python function args are passed by assignment

Comment: @AdamSmith what? I thought I was complicating the question by adding too much :) 
Anyway I'm worried about the same thing you were mentioning. I read multiple blogs about python's `call-by-object-reference` and it clearly confused me.

From what I could understand and from your comment, Am I correct in assuming that a object created that is binded to name `completeImageSet` is the same object that will be binded to name `imageParam` inside my function `filtered_imagesIds()` and hence no local copy of object is created ?

Comment: And also since I perform filtering on **mutable** object binded to 
 name `imageParam` and `completeImageSet` , Is the object modified? and therefore when the next iteration of the for loop runs and the `completeImageSet` is passed again to the function.... What does happen? does the function get the whole image set or filtered image set? Is a new object created? Ah!!! this is too confusing!

Comment: `completeImageSet` is calculated once (inside mainfunc) and never again. Its object is passed around to `filtered_imagesIds` which looks like it also creates a list, so you'll get that object creation happening `N` times (where `N = len(serverList)`), then `oldest_image` looks like it just selects an object there, so you're not incurring any extra penalty.

Comment: @AdamSmith Thank you so much! That's all I needed to know. If you can post the same thing as answer , I can mark it

Answer (score 1):

As Adam Smith mentioned, arguments are passed by object assignment, so the value of completeImageSet should not change as you iterate it over the loop.

You can also keep things simple using list comprehension instead;

```
oldImageList = [oldest_image(filtered_ImageIds(completeImageSet, server)) for server in serverList]
```

Comment: yes, Adam cleared the confusions I had and I will try list comprehension. Thanks for helping out